# How to fix 2 type arguments expected for class<T,T>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I wrote an adapter that accept ArrayList

```
class NumAdapter(val list: ArrayList<Property>) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<NumAdapter.ViewHolder>() {}
```

I pass this list through `myAdapter = NumAdapter(list)`, and the list contain

```
val list = ArrayList<Property>()
```

My property class:

```
data class Property(
    val name: String,
    val age: Int,
    val num: Int,
    val sisterAge: Int
    )
```

When I trying to accept ArrayList in my adapter, I get this error:

> 2 type arguments expected for Property

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Check that you've used the correct import and not `import android.util.Property`

Comment: You right that was the problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use wrong package of `Property`. Check it imported `Property` package in header class.